# How to find the latitude value and save it in another table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, shapefile, pgadmin-4

I have a shp file, I want to get the latitude value and store it in an another table.

```
CREATE TABLE Polepoints ( X varchar(50),Y varchar(50),Z  varchar(50));
```

Insert action :

```
INSERT INTO Polepoints (X) Select ST_X (ST_Centroid(geos)) from mytable
```

It throws out error

> column X doesn't exist

but the column and the table exists. I am a beginner.

Comment: There is no column `X` in table `Polepoints`.

Comment: No..it has..i dono where i make the mistake

Comment: If so, please provide a minimal reproducible example, as `create table` and `insert` statements, so one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: What is `(ST_Centroid(geos))`?

Comment: Since its a multi polygonal structure..normal query doesnt work for finding latitude value

Comment: Check in your table whether there is X column or not. Also check the case of the column text. IF it capital X then use "X" instead of X in insert script. Also data type for X should be double precision not text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to be somewhere else. If the table `Polepoints` really has a column named `X`, this error shouldn't appear (see example below). Check if you're connected to the right database or even if the real table `polepoints` (the one containing the column `X`) is in a different schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Polepoints ( X varchar(50),Y varchar(50),Z  varchar(50));

WITH mytable (geos) AS (
  VALUES ('POINT(1 1)'),('POINT(2 3)')
)
INSERT INTO Polepoints (X) SELECT ST_X (ST_Centroid(geos)) FROM mytable;

SELECT * FROM polepoints;

 x | y | z 
---+---+---
 1 |   | 
 2 |   |
```